# JS regex to split by line

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

How do you split a long piece of text into separate lines? Why does this return *line1* twice?

```
/^(.*?)$/mg.exec('line1\r\nline2\r\n');
```

> ["line1", "line1"]

I turned on the multi-line modifier to make `^` and `$` match beginning and end of lines.  I also turned on the global modifier to capture *all* lines.

I wish to use a regex split and not `String.split` because I'll be dealing with both Linux `\n` and Windows `\r\n` line endings.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
arrayOfLines = lineString.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

As Tim said, it is both the entire match and capture. It appears `regex.exec(string)` returns on finding the first match regardless of global modifier, wheras `string.match(regex)` is honouring global.

Comment: As a note, Tim's will match empty lines, wheras mine will not. Either may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Old answer, but i'd like to say that the reason `exec` returns on first match is because it's intended to be called multiple times for global regexes, until it returns null, and the regex stores things like `lastIndex` i.e. the index at which to start the next match.

Comment: Try `"123\n\n1234".match(/[^\r\n]+/g);` expected `Array [ "123", "", "1234" ]`, but got `Array [ "123", "1234" ]`

Answer (score 121):

Use

```
result = subject.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Your regex returns `line1` twice because `line1` is both the entire match *and* the contents of the first capturing group.

Comment: You need to use the `g` flag, and `\r` is a valid newline on some old apple machines.  Also, unicode defines `\u2028`, `\u2029`, and the old IBM newline `\u0085` as newlines.  So `/[\n\u0085\u2028\u2029]|\r\n?/g` handles all the edge cases.

Comment: @Mike: Are you sure about the `/g` flag? Doesn't make sense to have a split function that only splits once unless explicitly told otherwise. And Jojo said that he's dealing just with Linux and Windows. What next, EBCDIC?

Comment: @Mike: No, the `/g` flag is not required.  You can add it, but JavaScript just ignores it.  As Tim said, the default behavior is to split as many times as possible, but you can use the second argument to impose a maximum.

Comment: As for what constitutes a newline, it's even worse than that. According to the [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Line_Boundaries) we should always use `(\r\n|[\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029])`, no matter what platform the software runs on, or where the data comes from.

Comment: @Alan, quite right.  The `g` flag controls whether capturing groups are included in the output.

Comment: @Mike: The way I hear it, group captures are supposed to be included in the split results irrespective of flags.  That's what [Steven Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) says anyway, and I'm inclined to trust him.

Comment: Match is supposedly much faster than split: http://jsperf.com/regex-split-vs-match

Answer (score 29):

I am assuming following constitute newlines

1. \r followed by \n
2. \n followed by \r
3. \n present alone
4. \r present alone

Please Use

```
var re=/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/g;

arrayofLines=lineString.replace(re,"\n").split("\n");
```

for an array of all Lines including the empty ones.

**OR**

Please Use

```
arrayOfLines = lineString.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

For an array of non empty Lines

Comment: `\n` followed by `\r` is not a single newline

Comment: It is on some platforms. If you check Environment.NewLine in C# you will see \n\r

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 24):

Even simpler regex that handles all line ending combinations, even mixed in the same file, and removes empty lines as well:

`var lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/g);`

With whitespace trimming:

`var lines = text.trim().split(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g);`

Comment: The first one removes empty lines in the middle of the text but not at the beginning or the end.  That's fine for my purposes, I'm just pointing it out for anybody who needs the removal to be consistent.

Answer (score 9):

#### Unicode Compliant Line Splitting

*Unicode® Technical Standard #18* defines what constitutes [line boundaries](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Line_Boundaries). That same section also gives a regular expression to match all line boundaries. Using that regex, we can define the following JS function that splits a given string at any line boundary (preserving empty lines as well as leading and trailing whitespace):

```js
const splitLines = s => s.split(/\r\n|(?!\r\n)[\n-\r\x85\u2028\u2029]/)
```

I don't understand why the negative look-ahead part (`(?!\r\n)`) is necessary, but that is what is suggested in the Unicode document ‍♂️.

The above document recommends to define a regular expression meta-character for matching all line ending characters and sequences. [Perl has `\R`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#%5CR) for that. Unfortunately, JavaScript does **not** include such a meta-character. Alas, I could not even find a TC39 proposal for that.

Comment: good and working answer

Answer (score 6):

First replace all `\r\n` with `\n`, *then* `String.split`.

Comment: This takes two commands. Can it be done with regex in one command?

Comment: @JoJo: `myString.replace(/\r\n/, "\n").split("\n")` (unless you are asking because of academic interest :))

Comment: `'line1\r\nline2\r\n'.replace(/\r\n/, '\n').split('\n').without('');` produces a wrong second cell: `["line1", "line2\r"]`

Comment: @JoJo: Sorry, I forgot the `/g` flag for global! It should be: `myString.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n")`

Comment: Alright, but I thought regexes are supposed to let me do things succinctly in one line. I believe all regexes can be reduced to a bunch of `replace` and `splits`.

Comment: @Jojo: _This_ is succinctly in one line :) Regexes aren't the tool for every job. They can be very powerful, but should not be used everywhere. Note that `replace` _is_ a regex.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uq55en5o/

`var lines = text.match(/^.*((\r\n|\n|\r)|$)/gm);`

I have done something like this. Above link is my fiddle.

Comment: This leaves the line separator at the end.