# Javascript regex to split by lines starting with a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

My goal is to extract messages from an exported conversation that looks like this

```
inputText = `3/24/18 - Username : message here
3/24/18 - anotherUser : another message`
```

#### What I tried

My naive approach was to just split whenever I have a new line, I used
`arr = inputText.match(/[^\r\n]+/g)`
(Source : [JS regex to split by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034781/js-regex-to-split-by-line)) which does the work perfectly.

But now I'm facing a case that I didn't think about earlier, it's when a user sends a multi-line message, like:

```
inputText = `3/24/18 - Username : message here,
other text, same message
3/24/18 - anotherUser : another message`
```

The input of my first naive approach will output be wrong:

```
arr = ['3/24/18 - Username : message here',
       'other text, same message',
        '3/24/18- anotherUser : another message']
```

while I need it to be like this:

```
arr = ['3/24/18 - Username : message here message here too!!', 
       '3/24/18- anotherUser : another message']
```

I need to splitline but only when the line starts with the pattern `m/d/y - username :`

Comment: I define a message by its form, it always starts with a timestamp then the username then the message, but if there is a line that doesn't suit this it means that it's just a message which has to be in the previous line

apologies for the "obviously" part, I will edit it, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your lines always start with a date, formatted as in your example, then you could match that. Maybe it is somewhat easier with `split`

```js
var inputText = `3/24/18 - Username : message here
message here too!!
3/24/18- anotherUser : another message`;

var result = inputText.split(/[\r\n]*(?=^\d+\/)/m).filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

If you then want to replace the `\r` and `\n` with a space, add a `map`:

```js
var inputText = `3/24/18 - Username : message here
message here too!!
3/24/18- anotherUser : another message`;

var result = inputText.split(/[\r\n]*(?=^\d+\/)/m).filter(Boolean)
    .map(text => text.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, " "));

console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation

The regular expression breaks down into the following parts:

- `[\r\n]*`: any number of newline characters
- `(?=    )`: look-ahead to see whether pattern matches the next characters, without actually matching ("eating") them
- `^\d+\/`: the pattern that denotes the start of a line: one or more digits followed by a forward slash

Note that the regular expression will match the parts that should define the splits; those characters will not appear in the output. That is why the date-pattern is verified with look-ahead -- we don't want to lose those characters; they belong to the next line.

Because the very first characters of the input will match the split pattern, this will generate an empty string (for what *precedes* the split): this should be ignored. That is what `.filter(Boolean)` does. As empty strings are falsy, they will be left out by this filter.

Comment: Thank you that helps, can you please explain why you put the filter(Boolean), and if you can provide me a documentation page to read about those weird symbols like in .match(/[^\r\n]+/g) and split(/(?:[\r\n]*)(?=^\d+\/)/m) I will be grateful

Comment: I'm confused what is this and why it worked, please where can I read about it?

Comment: I added an explanation and simplified the regex it tiny bit. Let me know if this clarifies it. You can read about regexes on [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info).